# Complex series problem (basic complex variables)

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

first of all: I tried to use Taylor theorem but I couldn't figure it out.
second: how can I deal with $n=1$? how it changes the circumstances?

I want to show that $e^z=e+e$ $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{(z-1)^n}{n!}\right)$ when $|z|$ is less than finite

Comment: Please format math using $\LaTeX$. And what in the world do you mean by "less than finite"?

Comment: rightclick on this.. Choose the "math as' text command" $e^z=e+e$ $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{(z-1)^n}{n!}\right)$ and edit your question in the exact way you want it to be. Because the way you have presented is not clear

Comment: $e^{z}=e e^{z-1}$. Use Taylor series for $e^{z-1}$.

Comment: @salman (Welcome to Mathstack! ). You should write your code in between two dollar signs